# Symfony 4.4 LTS. How to disable serialization in cache?

Tags: symfony, caching, redis

I have symfony 4.4 LTS and TokenAuthenticator as guard. It is pretty dummy, just checks if there is a token in header X-API-TOKEN and checks the existence of this token in redis.
Not a big problem to check if there is a token in redis. The problem is to share this info with other microservices.

Auth use case checks the username and password and puts to redis user id as a value with key of 'auth_token.'.$authToken

```
Psr16Cache->set('auth_token.'.$authToken,$userIdUuid,10000);
```

The issue is that $userIdUuid is being serialized and I see in cache (through redis-cli) something like this

```
s:36:\"3fa99adb-5de4-4a68-8f0c-0fd6ee19ee46\";
```

As seen in the example the data was serialized. And I can't parse this into UUID from golang, nodejs, etc.

The question: How to disable serialization for Psr16Cache in Symfony 4.4LTS to be able to write/read raw data into/from redis?

Comment: Can you share more details? Why do you need to parse this in another language? And why can't you do this - the format is pretty fixed: for all UUIDs, the first part `s:36:\"` is the same, so you could simply split it of

Comment: This is a bad idea to rely on PHP's serialization in nodejs or Golang. I just need to write raw data into the cache. I can do it with a raw Redis connection created as a service in services.yaml, etc. But in this case, I will be tied to redis.

Comment: I don't think that this is possible after all, as disabling the serialization means that Symfony could not read from the cache again